# how to ensure consistent file hashes for Portable Applications with electron-builder

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron, electron-builder, portable-applications

How can i ensure that the file hash value is the same every time electron-builder build a `portable` application?

The premise is not to modify any code or resources, build it straight away twice directly.

my test porject is based on [electron-vite](https://electron-vite.org/guide/) framework:

```bash
npm create @quick-start/electron electron-builder-hash-test --template vue
```

[image]

I added a configuration to Electron-Builder.yml file, the rest is all default:

```yaml
win:
  target:
    - portable
```

I build it twice in a row, the result is different:

[image]
[image]

how does this work?

Is there any way to achieve that the build result files are the same without any changes?